# how get information from variable in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable X.

```
X="<table>...</table>"
```

How to get access to  information  in X using jQuery?

for example:

`X="<table> <thead> <tr> <td>id</td> <td>name</td> <td>mpg</td> <td>cylinders</td> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr> <td>1</td> <td>chevrolet chevelle malibu</td> <td>18.0</td> <td>8</td> </tr> <tr> <td>2</td> <td>plymouth satellite</td> <td>18.0</td> <td>8</td> </tr> <tr> <td>3</td> <td>amc rebel sst</td> <td>16.0</td> <td>8</td> </tr> </tbody> </table>"`

and I want to have information from 2 line.

Comment: What informations do you like to have?

Comment: Explain yourself better. Give us some context by adding more code maybe the real code

Comment: Why use jQuery on such thing?

Comment: $(x) and now u can call methods from jQuery like html() , addClass()...

Comment: X is a string, that is as much information you can get, from that code.

Comment: for example: 


X="<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<td>id</td>
<td>name</td>
<td>mpg</td>
<td>cylinders</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>chevrolet chevelle malibu</td>
<td>18.0</td>
<td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>plymouth satellite</td>
<td>18.0</td>
<td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>amc rebel sst</td>
<td>16.0</td>
<td>8</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>" 
And I wanna have information from 2 line.

Comment: [How jQuery Works](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access text information then you can use

```
$(x).find("element").text()
```

if you want to access html content of an element then you can use

```
$(x).find("element").html()
```

if you want to find element inside  then you can use

```
$(x).find("element")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
$(X).find("element").whatever
```

Example:

```
var x = "<div><span>hey</span></div>";
console.log($(x).find("span").text()); //logs "hey"
```

Answer (score 0):

With your specific question above, this will get you the text from the second row of the table...

```
var x = "<table> <thead> <tr> <td>id</td> <td>name</td> <td>mpg</td> <td>cylinders</td> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr> <td>1</td> <td>chevrolet chevelle malibu</td> <td>18.0</td> <td>8</td> </tr> <tr> <td>2</td> <td>plymouth satellite</td> <td>18.0</td> <td>8</td> </tr> <tr> <td>3</td> <td>amc rebel sst</td> <td>16.0</td> <td>8</td> </tr> </tbody> </table>";

alert($(x).find("tr").eq(2).text());
```

[Here's a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebhNj/)

If that's not what you want then you really need to tidy up your question and be more specific and helpful.  Help us to help you :)

Comment: Thank you. It is this, what I am looking for. If I want to have a colunm?  I wrote smth for  how to get data from column, but how apply this for my case. 



var colName = "name";

var arr = $('tbody>tr>td:nth-child(' + ($('thead>tr>td:contains("' + colName + '")')[0].cellIndex+1) + ')').map(function(){return $(this).text();});

Comment: Have a look at this... http://jsfiddle.net/ZmzhP/

Comment: thank you for your example. It ist almoust that, what I wanted. But I whant to get  only one column. My situation is,befor  table on web site I entered name of column and  then I use this name to get value from table.